# “There is the people” vs “there are the people”

Tags: grammatical-number

So, we got in a discussion with a friend about it. The whole sentence he mention was:

> There is the people with standards and the people who have fun.

By now we are pretty certain it should be *there are* but there's still some confusion here. On top of that, there are the lyrics of John Lennon's song *Immagine*:

> Imagine there's no countries

So that confuses everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existential construction takes *there* as a subject. *There* has no meaning, and often the verb takes its agreement from the complement of the verb *BE*. So if the Noun Phrase after *BE* is plural, the verb will be in a plural form. If the Noun Phrase is singular it will susually be singular:

- There **is** an antelope over there.
- There **are** some antelopes over there.

Notice, however, that in the examples above, the subject and the verb *BE* are not contracted. In normal speech these will nearly always be contracted. We will use *there's* instead of *there is*. It is also quite common nowadays to see them contracted in writing, and you can find instances in prestigious newspapers like the Times, for example.

Now when the subject *there* and *BE* are contracted like this, the verb doesn't need to agree in any way with the following Noun Phrase. Therefore with regard to the Original Poster's example:

> There is people with standards and people who have fun.

... this sentence would be regarded as ungrammatical by most, if not all speakers. However if they had contracted *there* and *BE*, then it would have been grammatical:

> There's people with standards and people who have fun.

This would have brought this into line with Lennon's:

> Imagine there's no countries.

Or sayings such as:

> There's many a slip twixt cup and the lip.

Or usages such as:

> There's times when I've wanted to box his ears

Having said this, despite the fact that this is a well documented aspect of the grammar, some nimby prescriptivists are bound to take offense at this. They will insist that it's ungrammatical to use a plural noun after *there's*. This will be despite the fact that they quite subconsciously actually use plural nouns after *there's* themselves quite frequently. They will appear about five minutes after I post this answer. They do make life fun though!

Comment: I was about to downvote, not because I disagree, but because this has been addressed here many times before. However, yours is the best version of the most acceptable answer I've found.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, I was tempted to downvote myself, myself;)

Comment: @Armen Ծիրունյան How do you define 'Standard English'? And does anyone else use your definition?

Comment: I'd have to disagree.  It should be "There're people with standards and people who have fun."  (I know that "there're" isn't a commonly written contraction, but it's frequently used in speech.)  And "Imagine there's no countries," aside from any poetic license, is saying "Imagine there is no concept of 'country'."

Comment: @HotLicks "When the copula is cliticised to the subject in informal style many speakers use the 3rd person singular for irrespective of the post-verbal NP" *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* Huddleston & Pullum 2002. I don't think Lennon would need to fudge his grammar to make that analogy! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria - Imagine if one could read that and understand what it meant.  (Or should it be "understood what it meant"?)